# Cheerio / Node.JS - retrieving an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, web-scraping, cheerio

Attempting to scrape the price element on this page:

http://us.asos.com/asos/asos-bomber-jacket-in-khaki/prd/5773457?iid=5773457&affid=14174&channelref=product%20search&mk=abc&currencyid=2&gclid=CIvXk9DEt88CFYpehgodLo0Ivg

Not able to get anything when running the `console.log`, any suggestions? I've checked that I am selecting the right element.

```
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');

var url = 'http://us.asos.com/asos/asos-bomber-jacket-in-khaki/prd/5773457?iid=5773457&affid=14174&channelref=product%20search&mk=abc&currencyid=2&gclid=CIvXk9DEt88CFYpehgodLo0Ivg';

request(url , function(error, response, html) {
if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    var $ = cheerio.load(html); 


    $('span.current-price').each(function(i, element){
        console.log($(this).text());

    })
```

Answer (score 0):

The `current-price` I see in that HTML is this:

```
<div class="current-price">
```

So, `$('span.current-price')` will not match that.

You need:

```
$('div.current-price')
```

or just

```
$('.current-price')
```

Comment: Hmm, still doesn't seem to be scrapping for me. Below is the element that I am trying to scrap, looks like its still within a <span> but I might be missing something. 

`<span data-id="current-price" data-bind="text: priceText(), css: {'product-price-discounted' : isDiscountedPrice }" class="current-price">$49.00</span> `

Comment: @kmpace - I don't see that element in the raw HTML of the page you referenced.  It is in the DOM once the page is loaded into a browser, but not in the raw source of the page so it must be getting added via Javascript.  Cheerio is only looking at the RAW HTML so it doesn't see it.